# JSON-API in NodeJS behind Apache webserver: Best practices to handle caching and compression?

Tags: apache, api, node.js, gzip, http-caching

I wrote a JSON-API in NodeJS for a small project, running behind an Apache webserver. Now I'd like to improve performance by adding caching and compression. Basically, the question is what should be done in NodeJS itself and what is better handled by Apache:

a) The API calls have unique URLs (e.g. /api/user-id/content) and I want to cache them for at least 60 seconds.

b) I want the output to be served as Gzip (if it's understood by the client). NodeJS's HTTP module usually delivers content as "chunked". As I'm only writing a response in one place, is it enough to adjust the Content-encoding header to serve it as one piece so it can be compressed and cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as my API has only a very very basic use, I'll go with an little in-memory key/value store as basic cache (based on the inspiration Simple Cache gave me). For this little development experiment, that should be enough. For an API in production use, I'd stick to Alfred's tipps.

For the compression I'll use Apache's mod_deflate. It's robust and I don't need async gzipping at this point. Furthermore you can change compression settings without changing the app itself.

Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2):

a) I recommend caching but without a timer, just let the replacement strategy remove entries. I don't know what you are actually serving, maybe caching the actual JSON or its source data might be useful. here is a simple cache I wrote including a small unit test to give you some inspiration.

[Simple Cache](https://gist.github.com/1047726)

b) How big is your JSON data? You have to compress it yourself, and keep in mind to not do it blocking. You can stream compress it and deliver it already. I never did that with node.

Comment: a) Thanks, I'll have a look at your caching script.
b) JSON is just a few KB. I forgot that Gzip should be non-blocking, too, so I think I'll use Apache's mod_deflate instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
> I wrote a JSON-API in NodeJS for a small project, running behind an
> Apache webserver.
```

I would just run the API on different port and not behind apache(proxy??). If you want to proxy I would advice you to use [NGINX](http://nginx.net/). See Ryan Dahl's [slides](http://s3.amazonaws.com/four.livejournal/20091117/jsconf.pdf) discussing Apache vs NGINX(Slides 8+). NGINX can also do compression/caching(fast). Maybe you should not compress all your JSON(size? few KB?). I recommendt you to read [Google's Page Speed "Minimum payload size" section](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#GzipCompression)(good read!) explaining that, which I also quote below:

> Note that gzipping is only beneficial for larger resources. Due to the
>   overhead and latency of compression and decompression, you should only
>   gzip files above a certain size threshold; we recommend a minimum
>   range between 150 and 1000 bytes. Gzipping files below 150 bytes can
>   actually make them larger.

```
> Now I'd like to improve performance by adding caching and compression
```

You could do compression/caching via [NGINX(+memcached)](http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/) which is going to be very fast. Even more prefered would be a CDN(for static files) which are optimized for this purpose. I don't think you should be doing any compressing in node.js, although some modules are available through [NPM's search](http://search.npmjs.org/)(search for gzip) like for example https://github.com/saikat/node-gzip

For caching I would advice you to have a look at [redis](http://redis.io) which is extremely fast. It is even going to be faster than most client libraries because node.js [fast client library(node_redis)](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) uses [hiredis](https://github.com/antirez/hiredis)(C). For this it is important to also install `hiredis` via npm:

```
npm install hiredis redis
```

Some benchmarks with hiredis

```
PING: 20000 ops 46189.38 ops/sec 1/4/1.082
SET: 20000 ops 41237.11 ops/sec 0/6/1.210
GET: 20000 ops 39682.54 ops/sec 1/7/1.257
INCR: 20000 ops 40080.16 ops/sec 0/8/1.242
LPUSH: 20000 ops 41152.26 ops/sec 0/3/1.212
LRANGE (10 elements): 20000 ops 36563.07 ops/sec 1/8/1.363
LRANGE (100 elements): 20000 ops 21834.06 ops/sec 0/9/2.287

> The API calls have unique URLs (e.g. /api/user-id/content) and I want
> to cache them for at least 60 seconds.
```

You can achieve this caching easily thanks to redis's [setex](http://redis.io/commands/setex) command. This is going to be extremely fast.

Comment: My hoster limits the public accessible port range and I have to proxy the requests through the installed Apache, so unfortunately nginx is not an option for me.  

But your advice was really helpful and I will consider it when it comes to a more professional project (in this case, it's just a little learning project for myself). I'll dig a little deeper into Redis, though. It sounds very promising.

Comment: @Frederic: Might wish to look into another host. Amazon has a free tier. Rackspace has VPSs starting out at like $10 a month. Linode has even better (valued) ones for $20 /month. Port filtering is a huge no-no for hosts in my book.